# I can't install "httpclient" for python

Tags: python, httpclient

My OS is Windows7 32bit & I use VScode and python 3.6 32bit

When I tried

C:\python>pip install client

```
Collecting httpclient
  Using cached httpclient-0.0.2.zip
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Downloading http://pypi.python.org/packages/source/d/distribute/distribute-0.6.19.tar.gz
    Extracting in C:\Users\Public\Documents\ESTsoft\CreatorTemp\tmptrynwiem
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\Public\Documents\ESTsoft\CreatorTemp\pip-build-b7pgq1re\httpclient\distribute_setup.py", line 143, in use_setuptools

        raise ImportError
    ImportError

    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\Public\Documents\ESTsoft\CreatorTemp\pip-build-b7pgq1re\httpclient\setup.py", line 13, in <module>
        use_setuptools()
      File "C:\Users\Public\Documents\ESTsoft\CreatorTemp\pip-build-b7pgq1re\httpclient\distribute_setup.py", line 145, in use_setuptools
        return _do_download(version, download_base, to_dir, download_delay)
      File "C:\Users\Public\Documents\ESTsoft\CreatorTemp\pip-build-b7pgq1re\httpclient\distribute_setup.py", line 125, in _do_download_build_egg(egg, tarball, to_dir)
      File "C:\Users\Public\Documents\ESTsoft\CreatorTemp\pip-build-b7pgq1re\httpclient\distribute_setup.py", line 99, in _build_egg_extractall(tar)
      File "C:\Users\Public\Documents\ESTsoft\CreatorTemp\pip-build-b7pgq1re\httpclient\distribute_setup.py", line 467, in _extractallself.chown(tarinfo, dirpath)
    TypeError: chown() missing 1 required positional argument: 'numeric_owner'
    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\Public\Documents\ESTsoft\CreatorTemp\pip-build-b7pgq1re\httpclient\
```

Comment: shouldn't you fire `pip install httpclient` instead of `pip installclient`??

Comment: Seems like a [known problem](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42329745/7976758) without a solution. What's that httpclient? Can you point to its home page or repo?

Comment: Oops I entered "pip install httpclient"

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.client.html

Comment: `http.client` is part of the python3 standard library and does not need to be installed - just import it in your code. `httpclient` is a third party package that must be installed. The github repo listed for it on pypi has disappeared, so I suspect it's abandonware.

Comment: Oh really??? Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

The [httplib](https://docs.python.org/2/library/httplib.html#module-httplib) module has been renamed to [http.client](https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.client.html) in Python 3. You don't need to install `http.client` in python 3.  It is pre-installed. So directly import it in your script as follows:

```
import http.client
```